# How can we enable the fingerprint login in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: login, 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

As I know, we don't need to install any library for Ubuntu 20.04 where we can enable by Settings → *Users* → *Authentication & Login*.

However, when I try to enable fingerprint login, I'm getting an error:

> Could not access any fingerprint readers Please contact your system administrator for help!

I have an inbuilt fingerprint sensor on my machine, but when using `lsusb`, I am not able to see the fingerprint driver.

Answer (score 10):

There is no driver available for most fingerprint readers for most Lenovo laptops at the moment, but to be sure to check by following these steps:

1. Install the `hw-probe` package:

   ```
   sudo apt install hw-probe
   ```
2. Run this command which creates a file with all devices, located in `/root/HW_PROBE/LATEST/hw.info/devices.json`:

   ```
   sudo -E hw-probe -all
   ```
3. Open the file created from the above command:

   ```
   sudo su
   gedit /root/HW_PROBE/LATEST/hw.info/devices.json
   ```
4. Find the fingerprint reader somewhere at the bottom of this file and if you see `"Status" : "failed"`, then there is no driver installed.
5. The first line of the fingerprint driver is something like this (example):

   ```
   "usb:28ck-58dk"
   ```
6. Open [this link](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?view=search) and write into *DeviceID* `58dk` (example, make sure to use the code you obtained in the previous step) and check which kernel the driver will be supported in.

Comment: All libfprint*  drivers are userspace drivers, not kernel drivers. You'll not be able to find driver w/o uploading the probe in your case because search is performed in the libfprint source code.

Comment: Are you sure ? Because I found for my Laptop that no driver is installed without uploading the probe..

Comment: Not installed, but may exist.

Comment: I tried this just now, but it created an empty devices.json file.