# Thinkpad T480 Finger Print Reader

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I got a T480 recently, and I am trying to use the Fingerprint reader on it. I installed `fprintd` and then ran `fprintd-enroll` but it hasn't worked as it says it can't find any device.

I'm really new to Linux, but would love to get my fingerprint reader working. I'm on 18.04.

Comment: Most of devices used by Lenovo are not supported.

Comment: see this for more information... https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250709/how-can-we-enable-the-fingerprint-login-in-ubuntu-20-04/1250812#1250812

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have gotten fingerprint login working on 18.04 and the sensor which comes with a T480s by using the [python-validity](https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity) project.

The basic install steps are

1. Remove any existing installs of `fprintd`

```
sudo apt remove fprintd
```

2. Add the python-validity PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:uunicorn/open-fprintd
sudo apt-get update
```

3. Install python-validity and dependencies

```
sudo apt install open-fprintd fprintd-clients python3-validity
```

4. Enrol a fingerprint

```
fprintd-enroll -f fprintd-enroll -f right-index-finger
```

5. Enable fingerprint login

```
sudo pam-auth-update
```

Comment: Confirmed it's working on elementary OS 6 Beta. Thanks!

Comment: This worked for me with a T480 on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

I have configured a fingerprint scanner on a Lenovo laptop. I used fprintd in order to get it working. I don't remember exactly what I did, but it is better to try this than nothing:

After you have installed fprintd, try to go in gnome-control-panel (I did it in Ubuntu 18.04, so if you are using a different distro it probably won't work). Scroll to the bottom and go to Details > Users > your user > between "automatic login" and "last login", I have an option that says "Login with fingerprint : Turned on". It might not have been so easy when I did it, but I don't remember what I did to configure it, so I don't have a good solution.

I would also try to reboot and try the enroll command again.

Comment: Hi, I tried this but when I click on the Fingerprint option (when it shows up) it says it can't find any devices.