# Native support for fingerprint login suddenly stopped in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, lenovo, thinkpad

When I initially installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my ThinkPad X1 Carbon (8th gen.), I was impressed by the fact that Ubuntu is now natively supporting fingerprint login using `libfprint`. I could set my fingerprint very easily in Settings > Users and use it for most of usages.

[image]

However, for quite some time, I have noticed that this stopped working (for no particular reason).

[image]

To investigate on this, I first used [`hw-probe` to confirm this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250709/how-can-we-enable-the-fingerprint-login-in-ubuntu-20-04), and it showed

```
usb:06cb-00bd;ff-00-00;failed;fingerprint reader;;Synaptics, Inc.;
```

That was quite disturbing. So I ran `lsusb`, and it showed:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc.
```

That did not help either because `06cb:00bd` belongs to the list of [supported devices of the `libfprint` project](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html).