# Fingerprint not working Ubuntu 23.10 | HP Laptop

Tags: hp, fingerprint-reader

I installed **Ubuntu 23.10** on my **HP Pavilion Laptop 14** but i can't see any fingerprint option, My laptop has inbuild fingerprint sensor. I want to set finger print lock.

[image]

Comment: Did you consider or try the steps [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-fingerprint.html.en)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can we enable the fingerprint login in Ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250709/how-can-we-enable-the-fingerprint-login-in-ubuntu-20-04)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue exactly with the same model.

Run this command:

`lsusb`

It will give you a list of all devices including the fingerprint device.

just identify the fingerprint device from the list and search for its ID on Google with your OS name.

in my case, my device ID was this: `04f3:0c00`
so I searched this ID and found a GitHub repo of the driver:

and found this solution: https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/libfprint/-/merge_requests/330#note_1718869